# Can partial classes in c# be used to modify functionality

Tags: c#, partial

Can I modify a function using partial classes like declaring it in one partial class and defining it in another partial class

```
public partial class PartialClass    
{        
    public void showa()
    {

    }
}
public partial class PartialClass
{
    string b = "b";
    public void showa()
    {
        Console.Write(b);
    }
}
```

or extending the functionality of a function in another partial class

```
public partial class PartialClass
{
    int a = 10; 
    public void showa()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
}

public partial class PartialClass
{
    string b = "b";
    public void showa()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a+b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer, but couldnt you inherit from PartialClass and then override the functionality of Showa()?

Comment: [partial methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx)?

Comment: Why not just try it? Writing this question probably took longer than writing just your code into LINQPad. Also, it's not clear what exactly you want to do. Partial classes and partial methods are used to help with auto-generated code.

Comment: Does it compile? I've not checked but I'd say no. Even if you could, this functionality would be very confusing.

Comment: K! Thanx for the suggestion, @StevenWood Will definitely try this

Comment: Why don't you use `abstract` classes and `interface`s instead?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but you need to use *partial methods* too:

```
public partial class PartialClass    
{        
    public void showa()
    {
        showaImpl();
    }
    partial void showaImpl(); 
}
public partial class PartialClass
{
    string b = "b";
    partial void showaImpl()
    {
        Console.Write(b);
    }
}
```

Now, if the code is compiled with just the first half - then `showa()` is an **empty method**. If the `showaImpl` implementation is declared - then the call exists. Calls to *partial methods* are ***completely ignored*** by the compiler if there is no implementation - and for this reason they cannot have an access modifier, or have a return value, or `out` parameters (since that would make definite assignment at the caller a nightmare).

Comment: Wow, does C# *really* allow that? Partially classes are evil enough as is, without adding this functionality too :(

Comment: @DavidArno primary use case is as an extension point for generated types (`.designer.cs`, etc); the generated code declares the partial methods, and includes calls to them in the expected places; then if the developer *implements* the partial classes, the calls exist; if they don't implement them: the calls don't exist. Take a look at the .designer.cs file for some sqlmetal or EF, to see what I mean.

Comment: @DavidArno I mean, let's face it: the problem of editing generated files and LINQ-to-SQL et  al is *basically* why the `partial` feature was added in the first place

Comment: OK, thanks Marc. My issue with such features is that they are great for their intended purpose (neatly handling auto-generated code that needs annotating) but folk have a habit of misusing such features. Anyway, that's just opinion and detracts from your answer. +1 anyway therefore.